# Unity displaces windows when switching workspaces

Tags: 12.04, unity, compiz, workspaces

This has happened to me on both the 12.04 installs I have tried.

Sometimes, maybe 3 times a day, when I switch workspaces to go to programs I leave open in other workspaces, the Window isn't there.  I find them in odd positions - for example, I just found my browser window half off the bottom of workspace 4, wrapped around to partly in the top of workspace 1.

What makes it more likely to happen appears to be when a window has a child window/dialog open.  The child is very likely to be displaced randomly?

Edit:  have switched off all extra workspaces - now just working in one, because I got tired of hunting down lost app windows.  Either no-one else is seeing this, or else no-one has any solution.

Comment: This case occurs when your movable half window is below the screen or in other workspace , and then on clicking to maximize it allocates itself to next workspace maximized.

Comment: No that is not what I am seeing.  The window is wholly on one workspace originally, but when I switch workspaces, unity displays it in some other position, sometimes half off workspace and half on another. No maximising involved either.

Comment: This is a known bug and currently being worked on: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/862430.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Thanks very much for the info.  I will just have to wait patiently then.

Comment: On further reading, I don't think it's the same bug.  That seems to be mainly about 'flickering' and I think I have seen that problem as well.  What I am seeing is that the window moves to a strange new place, and stays there.

Comment: I have a similar situation when I put a window into the right or left half of the screen with the compiz grid module. By default the hotkey is CTRL + ALT + NUM_PAD_4/6. When this happens the window bleeds over the workspace and I lose it to the next workspace, which gets annoying. So, I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

I have been experiencing this bug since a long time in 12.04. A fix has been released but it may take some time before it's backported to 12.04, check out these two bug reports:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1037164
https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz-plugins-main/+bug/755842